# unable to start server Glassfish 4 on eclipse unsing java 8

Tags: glassfish

I am configuring my computer for implement primesface and primefaces mobiles. I installed apache-tomcat, GlassFish 4 and java 8 (jdk 1.8). I configured GlassFish on eclipse, but when I want to start it, I receive this message

> Starting GlassFish 4 at localhost [domains1] has encountered a problem :
>
> Unable to start server due following issues:
>   Launch process failed with exit code 1

and the log file give me this

> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
>
> ERROR: Unable to create cache directory: C:\Program
>   Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
>
> ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to create cache directory.) java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
>   to create cache directory.    at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.(BundleCache.java:131)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.  at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
>   Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle
>   cache.    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:645)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache
>   directory.    at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.(BundleCache.java:131)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)    ... 1 more
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
>   Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:170)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:241)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:135)
>     ... 9 more Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m;
>   support was removed in 8.0

Can I have some solution please?

Comment: Can you check that this directory exists and is empty? `C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix`